# Retrofit --> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

None of the posts i found have helped me understand what im supposed to do. Stuck on this for quite a while so asking here. I want the List of IN and OUT names as "in" and "out" are json arrays. The error shows up as exception in OnFailure of response. getUsers() is in main activity.

```
private void getUsers() {


        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    APIInterface api = retrofit.create(APIInterface.class);

    Call<List<In>> call1 = api.getInUsers();
    call1.enqueue(new Callback<List<In>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<In>> call1, Response<List<In>> response) {
            List<In> inUsers = response.body();
            Log.v("InUsers",String.valueOf(inUsers));
            data.add(new Vote(Vote.HEADER_TYPE,"IN"));
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            for(In vote : inUsers) {
                data.add(new Vote(Vote.ITEM_TYPE,String.valueOf(vote)));
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<In>> call1, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage() + "IN LIST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

json is :

```
 {
 "message": "Hello World.",
 "planData": {
     "planId":"44444410",
     "votesData": {
         "votes": {
             "in":[ 
                 {
                     "firstName" : "Raj",
                     "lastName" : "Taj"
                 },
                 {
                     "firstName" : "Badger",
                     "lastName" : "Tagger"
                 },
                  {
                     "firstName" : "Candle",
                     "lastName" : "Bangle"
                 }
                 ] , 
                 "out" : [
                     {
                     "firstName" : "Bonnie",
                     "lastName" : "Clooney"
                 },
                 {
                     "firstName" : "Clyde",
                     "lastName" : "Hyde"
                 }
                 ]
         }
     }
 }
}
```

The Interface:

```
public interface APIInterface {
@GET("/")
Call<List<In>> getInUsers();

    @GET("/")
    Call<List<Out>> getOutUsers();
}
```

I got the models from http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

in example class there was only message and planId. I was calling the example class in interface initially. but thought the error might be because of that so changed it to List but nothing.

POJO code from the site:

```
>  
> -----------------------------------com.example.Example.java-----------------------------------
> 
> package com.example;
> 
> import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose; import
> com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
> 
> public class Example {
> 
> @SerializedName("message") @Expose private String message;
> @SerializedName("planData") @Expose private PlanData planData;
> 
> public String getMessage() { return message; }
> 
> public void setMessage(String message) { this.message = message; }
> 
> public PlanData getPlanData() { return planData; }
> 
> public void setPlanData(PlanData planData) { this.planData = planData;
> }
> 
> }
> -----------------------------------com.example.In.java-----------------------------------
> 
> package com.example;
> 
> import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose; import
> com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
> 
> public class In {
> 
> @SerializedName("firstName") @Expose private String firstName;
> @SerializedName("lastName") @Expose private String lastName;
> 
> public String getFirstName() { return firstName; }
> 
> public void setFirstName(String firstName) { this.firstName =
> firstName; }
> 
> public String getLastName() { return lastName; }
> 
> public void setLastName(String lastName) { this.lastName = lastName; }
> 
> }
> -----------------------------------com.example.Out.java-----------------------------------
> 
> package com.example;
> 
> import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose; import
> com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
> 
> public class Out {
> 
> @SerializedName("firstName") @Expose private String firstName;
> @SerializedName("lastName") @Expose private String lastName;
> 
> public String getFirstName() { return firstName; }
> 
> public void setFirstName(String firstName) { this.firstName =
> firstName; }
> 
> public String getLastName() { return lastName; }
> 
> public void setLastName(String lastName) { this.lastName = lastName; }
> 
> }
> -----------------------------------com.example.PlanData.java-----------------------------------
> 
> package com.example;
> 
> import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose; import
> com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
> 
> public class PlanData {
> 
> @SerializedName("planId") @Expose private String planId;
> @SerializedName("votesData") @Expose private VotesData votesData;
> 
> public String getPlanId() { return planId; }
> 
> public void setPlanId(String planId) { this.planId = planId; }
> 
> public VotesData getVotesData() { return votesData; }
> 
> public void setVotesData(VotesData votesData) { this.votesData =
> votesData; }
> 
> }
> -----------------------------------com.example.Votes.java-----------------------------------
> 
> package com.example;
> 
> import java.util.List; import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
> import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
> 
> public class Votes {
> 
> @SerializedName("in") @Expose private List<In> in = null;
> @SerializedName("out") @Expose private List<Out> out = null;
> 
> public List<In> getIn() { return in; }
> 
> public void setIn(List<In> in) { this.in = in; }
> 
> public List<Out> getOut() { return out; }
> 
> public void setOut(List<Out> out) { this.out = out; }
> 
> }
> -----------------------------------com.example.VotesData.java-----------------------------------
> 
> package com.example;
> 
> import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose; import
> com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
> 
> public class VotesData {
> 
> @SerializedName("votes") @Expose private Votes votes;
> 
> public Votes getVotes() { return votes; }
> 
> public void setVotes(Votes votes) { this.votes = votes; }
> 
> }
```

Comment: provide your PoJO's code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to do like below.

```
public interface APIInterface {
@GET("/")
Call<Example> getInUsers();

    @GET("/")
    Call<List<Out>> getOutUsers();
}
```

Your activity like below.

```
Call<Example> call1 = api.getInUsers();
    call1.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Example> call1, Response<Example> response) {
            List<In> inUsers = response. getPlanData(). getVotesData().getVotes().getIn();
            Log.v("InUsers",String.valueOf(inUsers));
            data.add(new Vote(Vote.HEADER_TYPE,"IN"));
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            for(In vote : inUsers) {
                data.add(new Vote(Vote.ITEM_TYPE,String.valueOf(vote)));
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Example> call1, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage() + "IN LIST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Awesome!! i saw the line "response.getPlanData().getVotes....." and knew that was it. But just to add, "response.get..." doesnt work.. "response.body().get..." works.

Comment: The values of String.valueOf(vote) is printing on my phone as "com.example.android.app.data.model.In@cc33c3c" etc. how would i fix this?

Comment: write, `inUsers.toString()`.

Comment: then you have to override toString method in all POJO class.

Comment: Actually i had to call getFirstName and getLastName too...    data.add(new Vote(Vote.ITEM_TYPE,vote.getFirstName.toString()));

Answer (score 1):

Right way to parse your server response

> Change your interface

```
@GET("/")
Call<Example> getInUsers();
```

> Change call

```
Call<Example> call1 = api.getInUsers();
    call1.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Example> call1, Response<Example> response) {
            List<In> inUsers = response.body().getPlanData().getVotesData().getVotes().getIn();
            ...your other  code here...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get Json Array from response but the rsponse contains JsonObject

Comment: My problem is exactly what you just typed dude. How do i get the damn names??? started retrofit yesterday so havent understood the working and concepts completely

Comment: Its easy to understand with simpler json with one main object and then just nested keys and another example with movies. but this json seems a little more complicated. so im getting confused

Answer (score 0):

The API doesn't return a `List<In>` or `List<Out>`. Instead, it returns an Example object. So instead of

```
public interface APIInterface {
@GET("/")
Call<List<In>> getInUsers();

    @GET("/")
    Call<List<Out>> getOutUsers();
}
```

you should use

```
public interface APIInterface {
    @GET("/")
    Call<Example> getUsers();
}
```

So your call should look like this:

```
Call<Example> call = api.getInUsers();
call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Example> call1, Response<Example> response) {
        // ... whatever you want to do with that data.
        // E.g. you can access inUsers via response.body().getPlanData().getVotesData().getVotes().getIn();
    }

    // ...
});
```

Comment: Really awesome of you. Thanks.