# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

When I call weather free API

https://api.apixu.com/v1/forecast.json?key=8f71b99b716f4278b98103446181912&q=Paris

Problems are

1. My post-man and using Call in Retrofit I get data
2. Using POJO class I get response error

> ERROR
>   Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

```
Call<List<DetailsMain>> listCall = api.getDetailsByParameter("8f71b99b716f4278b98103446181912", "Paris");

listCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<DetailsMain>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<DetailsMain>> call, Response<List<DetailsMain>> response) {
            DetailsMainList.setValue(response.body());
            Log.d("data", "" + response.body());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<DetailsMain>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("Error", "" + t.getMessage());
        }
});
```

Comment: Please do not share your API keys in public platforms or any question-answer websites. Someone may misuse those keys. Use dummy API key and post sample (JSON) response you get from server. Can you please [edit] the question and post POJO class here. That API returns JSONObject but in you're client you're expecting JSONArray (`List<DetailsMain>`) which is wrong and causing the above error.

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46581872/1343788

Comment: Share your POJO class

Answer (score 2):

Check your POJO. Check if it is in accordance with the response that you are receiving. According to the error that you mentioned, you are getting a JsonObject in your response for which you have declared a JsonArray in your POJO.

Comment: share your pojo here..Issue with you pojo you are getting JsonObject as data while you are looking for list (JsonArray) please correct your pojo

Comment: I added plus to you because you are young & pleasant. :) And also like to earn rating.

Comment: @CoolMind blagodaryu vas for appreciating :)

Comment: @ChandraniChatterjee, wow, you impressed me! Очень приятно вас слышать! Khoroshego dnya, devushka! :)

Comment: @CoolMind Вам тоже хорошего дня :)

Comment: @ChandraniChatterjee, хах, а в России вы бывали? :)

Comment: @CoolMind никогда не был в россии, но хотел бы когда-нибудь

Comment: @ChandraniChatterjee, приезжайте, вам было бы интересно. Возможно, я чуть позже пришлю вам новогодние фото Москвы.

Comment: @CoolMind
конечно .. я хотел бы это .. связаться со мной через LinkedIn или где-то

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187122/discussion-between-coolmind-and-chandrani-chatterjee).

Answer (score 1):

You are Receiving List in response which means json start from jsonArray but response is start from Json Object so code must like

```
Call<DetailsMain> listCall = api.getDetailsByParameter("8f71b99b716f4278b98103446181912", "Paris");
```

when you enqueue the retrofit request you have to change List also there ( otherwise compiler shows error)

Note : DetailsMain is your pojo class which you can generate from any online tool / android studio plugin.